# Is there a memmap functionality for pickle?

Tags: python

Is there a memmap functionality for pickle or torch.load()?

Ref: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: `mmap` module help you map the disk data into memory but the data need unpickle to be useful.

Comment: @Aaron numpy is not serialized. I cannot save huge data with numpy.  But then I need to load the whole pickle file first, and save it again unserialized, right?

Comment: yes if the unserialized is numpy.array. Complex objects cannot be saved without serialization.

Comment: @Aaron this does not help. Because I have data available as pickle. I would load it and save it again as `.npy`  (which might not be possible because too large) so that I can use mmap.

Comment: Given you can load it, use [`array.tofile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) to write it in raw binary format, not `npy`. Then the file can be later mapped with `numpy.memmap()`. Otherwise, find a powerful machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Using instead of pickle or `torch.save`/`torch.load`. It is better to use `tf.records`, e.g. from the PyTorch DALI plugin.